# Weird Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

> ***short version of the Question** : how it is possible, that my activity perform OnDestroy while starting a second activity and then perform OnResume after closing the new activity (and crash)*

I have a very confusing behaviour in the lifecycle of my app, its a bit complicatet but here the facts:

Its a fragment activity with the following intent-filters:

```
<intent-filter>
   <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost.de"></data>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the Activity am i able to start a second activity:

```
Intent LaunchIntent =  main_fa.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("de.myhost.calendar");
main_fa.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

In this new Activity might exist a link with the host host="myhost.de" from the intent filter above. Now I do the following:

I start the second activity from the first, the lifecycle of the first perform:
ON STOP
If I close the second activity, my firstone do:
ON RESUME

So far so good, but if i click the Link in the second activity, the firstone starts with several parameters and perform the lifecycle:
ON CREATE (without doing any ON DESTROY)

But now, if i start the second activity the second time, my first activity perform:
ON STOP
ON DESTROY

if I close the second one (without using a link) my firstone will perform
ON RESUME
and crash down, because of beeing not able to resume a destroyed activity...

Why did that happen and how to avoid this?

Comment: The first activity will be recreated after the other one finishes hence onResume is called

Comment: the problem seems to be, that the activitys starts each other and if i start the second activity the second time, the first instance will be destroyed and while destroying tihs instance, the first one, which was started by this instance will be destroyed too

Comment: It's going to be hard to trace this without logs. Log all the lifecycle events of both activities, add notes about where in the log you're pressing buttons to navigate, and post the results. It should be a lot clearer then.